# How to keep a webpage in tune with browser size ?

Tags: html, css

I apologize if I sound vague/ abrupt. 
The web page should be in tune with the browser size. I mean if the browser size is reduced/ shrunk, the full web page should also shrink and should be visible in the shrunk browser window. Is this possible ?

Comment: take a look into response website design :)

Comment: Read [ask] and create a [mcve]

Comment: @DZDomi Okay .. Thanks a ton amigo :)

Comment: @Alon,mplungjan Thanks but I know how to ask a question. I knew 'this' question was abrupt. That's why I mentioned it while asking. This was urgent, that's why I rushed things up this time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to use media queries for a responsive layout in your css
Example:

```
@media screen and (max-width: 699px) and (min-width: 300px) {
<css template for 300 to 699 px width goes here>}
```

You can also use bootstrap (a responsive framework which has predefined classes for what you may need) for a faster implementation.

Comment: Will try.. Thanks for the answer pal